# RHEL6 server - fonts garbled on jsp viewer but perfect on exports (from same viewer) if fonts added to java font dir, else null pointer exception

Tags: java, linux, fonts, crystal-reports

Here's an odd one. So I've been running this on a mac so far and all's been well (the server that is, the designer is on Windows obviously). Have just deployed to a linux box (Red Hat) and initially the pdf export had a null pointer exception on OpenTypeFontManager. This suggested it couldn't find the font, so I copied the relevant ttfs to $JAVA_HOME/lib/fonts and the pdf worked perfectly. The downside is that suddenly the charts on the viewer went pretty garbled (all font output was messed up, with fonts ). Remove the files again and all returns as was, put them back and pdfs work and charts are garbled.

An example...

[image: Bad Font]

Note this doesn't happen in PDF export, only in the viewer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, another thick one for me. Server had openjdk which crystal hates, I swapped it out with a proper sun jdk and all was right with the world. Sorted.

Answer (score 1):

After is another possibility to switch off the font embedding from the result PDF is this is feasible.
There is an init file in CrystalReportsRuntime.jar which defines the behaviour here. It is located at com\crystaldecisions\reports\exporters\page\pdf\PDF_properties.xml, and there are 4 boolean definitions. Go edit this file, and set the default value for "embedFonts" to "false".